# R, about "rm" function

Tags: r

Let
x = 3

If I type rm(x) in the R console, there is no variable in the workspace.
Since x is a numeric type of data, I thought rm(3) would also work.
But R pops up an error message. What's wrong with the statement rm(3) ?

Comment: You trying to reduce the set of integers so that it doesn't include the number 3?

Comment: What if you had `x <- 3; y <- 3` and `rm(3)` behaved as you describe?  That would not be a very practical "feature" *at all.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, just because `x = 3` does not mean that `3 = x`. You're defining x to be equal to the value of three, but 3 can also be the value of other things as well. It wouldn't make any sense to remove any usage of the number 3. x is a string; 3 i a number. Make sense?